# Format numeric values in Filemaker 12 List() result

Tags: report, filemaker

I'm using List() to retrieve a numeric field which I subsequently display on a report view via a merge variable inside a text field.  The data being displayed is a list of employees who worked on a particular job on a particular day, and the number of hours they worked under various classifications (normal, overtime, non-billable, non-billable overtime, et al).  The hours are all calculated fields pulled from another table, but they need to be stored numerically.

Each column has its own text field:

```
| <<$$Name>> | <<$$normalHours>> | <<$$otHours>> | ...
```

Giving output such as:

```
Jim Jones           8      2
Ralph Ryder      4.25      0
Foo McBar          10    2.5
```

The field height needs to be dynamic because there could be anywhere from 1 to 10 or so employees displayed.

**The issue** is that I would like to always display the hours field with two decimal places:

```
Jim Jones         8.00      2.00
Ralph Ryder       4.25      0.00
Foo McBar        10.00      2.50
```

This is normally trivial via Inspector -> Data for a single-value field, and perhaps it still is trivial -- but I'm just not seeing it.

I've tried using SetPrecision(hours ; 2) when populating the field, and also (though I didn't think it would actually work) when creating my list variable:

$$normalHours = SetPrecision( List( laborTable::normalHours ) ; 2 )

In both cases I still see plain integer output for whole numbers and no trailing zeroes in any case.

Please let me know if I can provide any further information that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things you can try:

#### Auto-enter calculation replacing existing value

You could change your normalHours field to be an auto-enter calculation, uncheck 'do not replace existing value', and set the calculation to the following:

```
Let ( [
    whole = Int ( Self ) ;
    remainder = Abs ( Self ) - Abs ( whole )
] ;
    Case ( remainder = 0 ;
        whole & ".00" ;
        Self )
)
```

This will append a ".00" to any whole numbers in your field. This should then come through your List() function later.

#### New calculation field

Alternately, if you don't want to automatically modify the existing number, you could make a new calculation field with a very similar calculation:

```
Let ( [
    whole = Int ( normalHours ) ;
    remainder = Abs ( normalHours ) - Abs ( whole )
] ;
    Case ( remainder = 0 ;
        whole & ".00" ;
        normalHours )
)
```

And then you would use that calculation field in the List function, instead of your normalHours field.

For more complicated field formatting, you could also use a custom function like this: http://www.briandunning.com/cf/945

Comment: This works well, particularly because the field already was a calculation.  I was momentarily worried because this field is subsequently used in other calculations but FM can easily handle casting text back to numeric value.  I was close to this when I tried using SetPrecision in the calculation (though as I suspected it didn't work).  I just didn't think of it this way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this with a portal, perhaps?

If not, then try to set formatting on the merge text field itself. It can have formatting too; only one variant for each data type, but in your case it should be enough.

Comment: I'm experimenting with using portals now.  This works very well if I can accurately predict the size of my data.  Since I don't know of a way to dynamically expand portal height, I'm just having to guess at how many rows I could conceivably need.